# How to repeat specific request multiple times when loop controller cannot serve the purpose?

Tags: loops, jmeter, controller, timestamp

The requirement is we have 4 requests req1, req2, req3, req4. Since, we have to add pass 20 days data, we are using ${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,,-P${__intSum(21,-${__counter(FALSE,)},)}DT2M,,)} to serve date purpose under loop controller for 20 loop count.

But here, req1 we want to call 3 times for same date and rest others just once. When we are adding loop controller(3 times) to req1 under parent loop controller, the date is 2021-04-14 12:12:02, 2021-04-15 12:12:02, 2021-04-16 12:12:02 each times its called for all requests BUT what we want is:

req1 to be called thrice per day 2021-04-14 12:12:02, 2021-04-14 12:12:02, 2021-04-14 12:12:02.
req2, req3, re4 2021-04-14 12:12:02 once only.

When loop controller was added to req1 for 3 times loop, it did not work. It shows 2021-04-14 12:12:02, 2021-04-15 12:12:02, 2021-04-16 12:12:02

Please help.

```html
    Thread group
----Parent loop controller(20 count so as to add past 20 days record starting from 2021-04-14 12:12:02, 2021-04-15 12:12:02, till 20 days)
------req1(want to call this request 3 times per day 2021-04-14 12:12:02,2021-04-14 12:12:02,2021-04-14 12:12:02)
------req2(just once per day)
------req3(just once per day)
------req4(just once per day)
```

This is how it looks currently.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) which produces incremented value **each time it's being called**, if you need the described behaviour you need to amend your test as follows:

- Loop Controller (3 count)

  - req 1 `${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,,-P20DT2M,,)}`
- Loop Controller (20 count)

  - req 1 `${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,,-P${__intSum(21,-${__counter(FALSE,)},)}DT2M,,)}`

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)

Also be aware that there is `${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) which exposes the current iteration of the Loop Controller so you might want to use it instead of the __counter() function

Comment: above configuration gives different date for req1 if hit thrice using loop controller.

Comment: oh, with above example, I can see 4 times iterated for 14th april, 2021. I dont see occurance of same request 4 times on next day on 15th april, 2021 and so on.

Comment: How can I get that?